# SQL Query to find out Sequence in next or subsequent rows of a Table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Table with following structure

```
Timestamp(DATETIME)|AuditEvent
---------|----------
T1|Login
T2|LogOff
T3|Login
T4|Execute
T5|LogOff
T6|Login
T7|Login
T8|Report
T9|LogOff
```

Want the T-SQL way to find out What is the time that the user has logged into the system i.e. Time inbetween Login Time and Logoff Time for each session in a given day.

```
Day (Date)|UserTime(In Hours) (Logoff Time - LogIn Time)
--------- |   -------
Jun 12    |   2
Jun 12    |   3
Jun 13    |   5
```

I tried using two temporary tables and Row Numbers but could not get it since the comparison was a time i.e. finding out the next Logout event with timestamp is greater than the current row's Login Event.

Comment: Post you source sample data that your result is produced from.

Comment: Your data has no date column.

Comment: Timestamp would be the date Column.

Comment: Is T7 correct? Can you have two login without a logoff?

Comment: Yes It can because of the current setup, The systems I am dealing with does put a login twice. And I must consider the older login time and the next latest logout time when computing the UserTime/SessionTime. So it will be Date Part of T6 | {T9-T6}

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the records.  I would suggest counting logins or logoffs.  Here is one approach to get the time for each "session":

```
select min(case when auditevent = 'login' then timestamp end) as login_time,
       max(timestamp) as logoff_time
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when auditevent = 'logoff' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by timestamp desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

You then have to do whatever you want to get the numbers per day.  It is unclear what those counts are.

The subquery does a reverse count.  It counts the number of "logoff" records that come on or after each record.  For records in the same "session", this count is the same, and suitable for grouping.

Comment: The counts in the second table are the time different between the login and logoff time like 2Hrs30Mins. Sorry I must have been clear there.Thanks I will try this.